# CSS nested navigation with children on next line

Tags: html, css

I'd like to build a nested navigation with `ul` and `li` which can also have subitems.

The sub items should appear on the next line, when a parent `li` has the `ative` class on it (the class is set onclick with javascript).

I managed to do that bu only if the sub-list has `position: absolut`.
Unfortunately it then overlaps the following content.

This is how it looks:

[image: navigation]

I'd really like to do this without having to use `position: absolut`, but cannot think of a way.

Can anyone help me?

Following the code I have.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid deeppink;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
}

ul ul li {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul li.isActive {
  background-color: yellow;
}

ul li.isActive ul {
  display: block;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>top1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="isActive">
    <span>top2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>sub1</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>sub2</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>top3</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>other sub1</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>other sub2</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<span>
        Some text.
        </span>
```

Comment: _"Unfortunately it then overlaps the following content."_ - the alternative, not absolutely positioning the sub menus, would push the rest of the site content down when shown. That usually looks messy; especially if you have sub menus of different heights due to number of items. Usually what you have now is what people want ...

Comment: Yes but I want that. But I don't know how to achieve it. When I take the absolut out, it looks completely  wrong...

Comment: Getting it to look the same is not going to be easy without absolute positioning, granted. But since JS is in play anyway, you might as well add a corresponding margin-bottom to the main ul to achieve the effect. If you're sure your sub menus will only ever cover one "line", then you might use a static value (preferably in something relative to the font size), otherwise query the height of the specific sub menu shown first and assign that value dynamically ...

Comment: That's what I feared :S Hoped it would be possible without stuff like this, but I almost expected it's not...

Answer (score 0):

Not the most dynamic way or very expandable but you could use the focus pseudo and you wouldn't need to use JavaScript for the active, and you don't want to use any more JS I see from your comments. JSFiddle here to see it in action https://jsfiddle.net/Le64we9s/1/

Style:

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}

.content{
  margin-top:10px;
}

.main-link, .sub-link{
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#2489f1;
}

.sub-link{
  background:#1d6dbf;
  display:none;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.main-link:focus{
  background:#65b1ff;
}

.main-link-1:focus ~ .sub-link-1, .main-link-2:focus ~ .sub-link-2, .main-link-3:focus ~ .sub-link-3, .main-link-4:focus ~ .sub-link-4{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

You would have to add `.main-link-(number here):focus ~ .sub-link-(same number here)` every time you add a new main menu tab and a sub menu.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="main-link main-link-1">Main 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="main-link main-link-2">Main 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="main-link main-link-3">Main 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="main-link main-link-4">Main 4</a>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-1">Sub Menu 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-1">Sub Main 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-1">Sub Main 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-1">Sub Main 1</a>

    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-2">Sub Menu 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-2">Sub Main 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-2">Sub Main 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-2">Sub Main 2</a>

    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-3">Sub Menu 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-3">Sub Main 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-3">Sub Main 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-3">Sub Main 3</a>

    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-4">Sub Menu 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-4">Sub Main 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-4">Sub Main 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="sub-link sub-link-4">Sub Main 4</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  content here
</div>
```

You need to use a tags for the focus pseudo to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this and modify it accordingly.I didn't use *position:absolute*

```css
 ul > li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
 list-style:none;
 }
 
 ul > li > span{ 
 border:1px solid red;
 display:block;
 width:50px;
 }
 .sub{ margin-left:-132px;margin-top:5px; }
 
 .sub > li{
    float:left;
   margin-left:20px;
   border:1px solid red;
   visibility:hidden;
 }
 
 ul > li:hover .sub > li{
    visibility:visible;
 }
 
 #txt{
   margin-left:60px;
   clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><span>top 1</span></li>
 <li><span>top 2</span>
   <ul class="sub">
     <li>Sub 2.1</li>
  <li>Sub 2.2</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><span>top 3</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="txt">
 <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
```